# Compiler error despite catching IOException

Tags: java, exception

The following program for file I/O is taken from the standard Oracle docs:

```
//Copy xanadu.txt byte by byte into another file
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyBytes
{
    public static void main(String[] args) //throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try
        {
            in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
            out = new FileOutputStream("xanadu_copy.txt");
            int c;

            while((c = in.read()) != -1)
            {
                out.write(c);
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IO exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (in != null)
            {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null)
            {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I commented out the `throws IOException` part, thinking that since I'm catching it in the code, all should be fine. But I'm getting a compiler error:

```
CopyBytes.java:32: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                in.close();
                        ^
CopyBytes.java:36: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                out.close();
                         ^
2 errors
```

The errors vanish when I include the `throws IOException` part, but I'm confused. Isn't it enough that I'm catching the exceptions?

Comment: Did you look at where the compiler says the error is? Hint: it's not `in.read(c)` or `out.write(c)`.

Comment: @immibis I got it now, after reading the answers below. Foolish me. :P

Comment: I mean *where*... as in, the filename and line number, right at the start of each error.

Comment: @immibis Yes, I got it now. Wasn't thinking straight, I guess. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your finally block you are using `in.close()` statement to close the stream. This statement also throws `IOException`. 
You can avoid this exception by adding `try/catch` block to these close statements.

Answer (score 6):

You are not catching the potential IOException that might be thrown in your finally block.

You can fix it by adding try-catch to the finally block:

```
    finally
    {
      try {
        if (in != null)
        {
            in.close();
        }
        if (out != null)
        {
            out.close();
        }
      }
      catch (IOException ex) {
      }
    }
```

Comment: `catch(IOException ex) {}` is a bad idea - if an exception happens, the program won't tell you that something went wrong. Put `ex.printStackTrace()` at the very least.

Comment: @immibis There's not much you can do about this exception when closing the streams. What would you do if you see this stack trace in some log file?

Comment: then the stack trace would tell you *why* the stream failed to close. (Full hard disk and stuff buffered, for example)

Answer (score 3):

In order to not have to report an exception you need to put it in the `try` portion of the `try/catch/finally` block. Exceptions thrown in the `catch` and `finally` parts are not caught, prompting the compiler error:

```
try {
    ... // Exceptions thrown from here will be caught
} catch (ExceptionOne e1) {
    .. // Exceptions thrown from here need to be declared
} catch (ExceptionTwo e2) {
    .. // Exceptions thrown from here need to be declared
} finally {
    .. // Exceptions thrown from here need to be declared
}
```